# Is it possible to write Boot loader software without architecture specific registers?

Tags: microcontroller, cpu-registers, bootloader, uart, armv7

I'm curious to know, is it possible to write **Boot-loader** software independent of Processor architecture specific registers? f.e., **ARMv7** have its own specific registers for drivers, i like to know the difference between the following approach.

1). write **Bootloader** based on Arch specific registers(let's say **UART** driver)
2). write **Bootloader** independent of Processor arch specific registers

Which case could be faster?

Comment: The purpose of a bootloader is to fetch, and usually to install, code from an I/O device. In practice the source device will be interfaced with by some form of I/O registers, your only option is whether this is handled directly by your own code, delegated to a library which you choose to embed or provided in ROM by certain devices. Can you elaborate on more precisely what you want to achieve here, and perhaps on what sense of `faster` you are referring to?

Comment: It's also not entirely clear what you mean by "architecture specific registers", because UARTs and other peripherals have _nothing whatsoever_ to do with the CPU architecture. Just look at how many completely different systems have 8250 derivatives in them, for instance.

Comment: Yes to a point, uboot, redboot, etc for example.  but you do have to get processor and chip/system specific at some layer otherwise what is the point?  It is a bootloader after all...